# BackBone model: format current dateTime

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have such model:

```
app.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    title: '',
    created_at: Date(),
  }
});
```

js Date() is good, but when I try to format it, I get many errors on each time. Didn't know what's going on.

How could I format this default date to a format like: `d.m.Y H:i` ?

Ï need it for storing, not for viewing

Is it possible to do without any libs?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Date/time values are always stored as numbers (timestamps). Formatting make sense only on output

Comment: @hindmost it make sense in my app!

Comment: Is any reason to store Date/time as formatted string?

Comment: @hindmost yep, didn't mind about that) i need solution as in question

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)' functions for formatting dates.